# no suitable module for running kernel found after update

Tags: kernel, updates

after some update of 12.04 at start up, black screen shows up with things written on it and there's an error. a red star and then "no suitable module for running kernel found". I have only one option left and that is upgrade to 14.04 which i don't like to do it. pls help.

Comment: You can boot with a previous kernel from grub menu.